# In odoo, how to integrate supplier and customer invoices on payments?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

When a partner is Customer, and Supplier it can make you in_invoice, in_refund, and you can make him an out_invoice, out_refund.

But if if you have for the same partner out_invoice $1000 and in_invoice $500,it would have to should that in_invoice with the in_refunds from the same partner on the customer payment form...

How do odoo solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you register payment directly from invoice itself, you are actually making payment towards that invoice only. but if you go to customer payments menu and create a record and select the partner(or parent company) of that invoice, then you will be able to see the credit and debit outstanding invoices and it will be automatically selected each other. If you are paying any extra you can add the amount and then process it to reconcile the invoices of that customers.

Comment: No, in "customer payments" I can't see debits is they are "in_invoices".
And in "supplier payments" can't see on the debits "out_invoices"

Comment: are you sure its the same partner you have used for the customer invoice and supplier invoice?

Comment: Yes its the same partner! See this: http://pho.to/AA6WQ
I think in the customer payments not only the customer payments should be debit but also purchase invoice if that partner it's also a supplier, is there a native way to do that, or a module?